# Asp.Net Core 2.2 MVC - Set up default route to a controller in the sub folder

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc-2.0

I have just started exploring routing in ASP.Net Core 2.2 MVC. I took the default project template and just changed route.MapRoute to always default to LoginController under Views

ex: Account/LoginController.cs with an Index method.

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "Account/{controller=Login}/{action=Index}");
```

I get an error when I hit https://localhost:44364 in the browser

But the controller gets called when i copy this https://localhost:44364/Account/Login in the browswer.

How can i make the default route https://localhost:44364 to always hit LoginController under AccountFolder.

This is a basic set up for any website with a login page.
Could someone help me with this. I am  wasting a lot of time here.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Account/Login}/{action=Index}");
```

The other way you could do it is use areas, however your project doesn't use them. If you do decide to use areas, this would be the code for route

```
routes.MapRoute(
      name: "default",
      template: "{area:Account}/{controller=Login}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```